# Common output directory, Web Applications and IIS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express

I have changed the output path for all my projects to use same location.  I.e:

[image: Web API output path]

My ASP.NET Web API projects have now stopped working when running them in debug using IIS Express.

It seems that IIS Express is pointing to the existing Web Application project directory:

[image: IIS Express]

Should this not be pointing now to the `..\Build\bin\Debug` common output directory? How do I configure this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change .net mvc bin dir location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263002/is-there-a-way-to-change-net-mvc-bin-dir-location)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no clean way to do this. For security reason, IIS requires you use the 'bin' folder right under the web project folder as the output directory.

It is still possible to achieve your goal though. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263002/is-there-a-way-to-change-net-mvc-bin-dir-location/13263992#13263992).