# What is compilation tag in web.config or app.config for?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config

I've noticed there is a `compilation` section in `web.config` like:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo.v15.2, Version=15.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.ExpressApp.v15.2, Version=15.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Persistent.Base.v15.2, Version=15.2.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
```

What is it for? Where are these assemblies being added?

Comment: This may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530683/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-assemblies-node-in-web-config

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=compilation%20config%20section

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.71).aspx